# Creating and saving maps with tiles in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make a "dungeon crawler" type game demo, and this is my first time really making anything beyond Pong & Pac-Man clones. My big hang up right now is creating the actual level. I've gone through a tutorial on how to draw tiles onto the screen, but I can't find anything about where to go from there.

How do I go from one screen to making a larger dungeon? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You should consider starting off by using 2 dimensional arrays.
In this manner, you can represent your data visually quite easily.

Start off with an initialization:

```
//2D array
int[,] array;
```

Some sample data:

```
array= new int[,]
        {
            {0, 2, 2, 0},
            {3, 0, 0, 3},
            {1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 0},
        };
```

Create yourself an enumeration, which will index each integer in your map:

```
enum Tiles
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Dirt = 1,
    Water = 2,
    Rock = 3
}
```

Then load your textures and what not by looking through your array one item at a time.  Based on your texture size, you can easily draw your textures on screen as presented in your map:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array[0].Count; j++)  //assuming always 1 row
    {
       if (array[i][j] == (int)Tiles.Undefined) continue;

       Texture = GetTexture(array[i][j]);  //implement this

       spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Vector2(i * Texture.Width, j * Texture.Height), null, Color.White, 0, Origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Extremely useful for a beginner like myself. @Jon, Would you know of any resources online that talk about this? Trying to find just the basic stuff has proved a massive waste of time. I've spent over 3 weeks looking for what should be basic stuff (like making a ball roll along a platform) and I still have not found anything.

Comment: @ĈħőşęņŎńę You can take a look at the tile engine tutorial on XNA Resources.  It does a pretty good job at explaining the concepts:  http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=TUTORIALS

Making a ball roll along a platform may sound basic, but is actually somewhat complex.  You are dealing with movement, collision detection, and collision response.

Answer (score 1):

The PSK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx is a demo created by Microsoft that uses an ASCII file to create the levels. There are also many demo's and tutorials and other things for it. It's the same approach that Jon described.

example:

```
.......
.....e.
xx...xx
..s....
```

Where a dot is empty space, s is the start location and e is the enemy. Because you know that every tile is (for example) 32x32 pixels you simple position the 's' at coordinate (2x32,3*32).

There are many many ways to handle this tough.

For making more than one screen you need to implement a camera class. What you probably want is a scrolling level. But I'd advise you to first learn to make a single screen from an array, ascii file, etc. before going any further.

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier to design your map, if you implement save/load for [tiled map format](http://www.mapeditor.org/index.html).